# ASP.NET Model binder cannot bind collection of complex of object containing collections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, extjs, model-binding

I sumbmit folliwing json via an ajax call to the mvc controller. JSON contains one property which is just and `int`. and another property which is an collection of `objects` and that `object`s themselves have collection of `otherobject`s and the properties of `otherojbect` are promitive types. the thing is that if I sumbit just the second property of that `json` (collection of complex `object`s) model binder does a very good job and binds it to model but when i submit that collection of `object`s alongside with the primitive `int` model binder just binds `int` property and the seccond property is just empty collection. I use ext-js ajax call. I tried submiting json with `params` property and with `jsonData` property nothing seems to work ? what is the best solution to this problem. any help would be appriciated.

```
public class ModelToBind
{
    public int IntParam { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CompexObject> ComplexObjectParam { get; set; }
}

public class CompexObject
{
    public int AnotherIntProp { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<AnotherComplexObject> AnotherComplexObject{ get; set; }
}

public class AnotherComplexObject
{
    // some primitive properties here
}

public JsonData DoSomething(ModelToBind model)
{
    model.IntParam; // this property is binded
    model.ComplexObjectParam; // this is binded as empty collection
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: here is the core @Maess

Comment: Post your javascript and view please

Comment: Is there a big chance that it ia a javasvript problem ? Because I thing that everything is being posted quiet well its juat an model binder problem. I cannot post javascript. And why do you need view ? I@Maess

Comment: It's likely an issue with how you are posting the data, hence wanting to see the js or view code.

Comment: okay thanks. If I would be able I will post the json here @Maess

Answer (score -1):

What are your action's parameters ?

Logically, if you want to bind {int - Object}, you should have a c# type with the same properties like

```
public class MyType{
     public int MyPrimitive{get;set;}
     public MyOtherType ComplexType{get;set;}
}
```

and this type as a parameter of your action.
Of course, other scenarios are possible, but we need more information about your action.

Comment: this is not the case. please see the edit, i have posted some code

Comment: you got a collection, it's not just a type, we need to see the client side. Logicially a collection can be posted like ComplexObjectParam [0].property=... COmplexObjectParam[1].property=